# ubuntu main machine unaccessable via any network service, while virtual lxc machines are accessable

Tags: networking, lxc

First I would like to apologize for my writing, English is my second language and I am far from the best for giving a proper description.

I run a lenovo laptop as a server, since it is what I got to use at the moment.
It is running Ubuntu 20.04 server, with 4 lxc virtual machines on it, that all is using an image of ubuntu 20.04. The usages of the virtual machines is as follows:

1: a local dns server, to manage local domain names, since I am to lazy to keep remembering ip addresses.
2: a ldap server for user handling, since I have a few users and I also want to learn more about services like this.
3: a mariadb server, for having a single machine using a mariadb server, instead of having serval, in case I am going to use several different services that want their own database.
4: a machine running a web server with nextcloud.

At the lenovo host machine, I have a few usb harddrives, that I was otherwise not using, since I have a more dedicated NAS/SAN, depending of what you want to call it. The lenovo laptop are sharing one of these usb drives, via sftp, since I use openssh to connect to it and did not want to use additional services on the machine. The usb harddrive is used for the nextcloud machine, to give additional space. This was set up before I really found out about mounting existing directories in lxc.

But here is my problem. When the lenovo machine appers to be stresed for some time, the main machine at some point is no longer accessable via any network service. I can not send a ping, I can not connect via ssh or webmin, that I have installed to help manage it. But the other machines, hosted on it, like the dns machine, or nextcloud machine, can be accessed as nothing has happened.

I would like to say, that I use ipupdown on the lenovo machine where I use the /etc/network/interfaces file with a bridge for the lxc machines to use to get their own ip addresses from. Basically so they look like they are individual machines on the network.

Is there any that has an idea of what I can do to not loose access to the main machine over the network, both so the nextcloud machine can use it, but also, mostly, so I can do maintenance on the lenovo machine, in case that is needed?

Comment: Can you post the network configuration of the main host and from the containers too.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
The host machine uses ifupdown, the /etc/network/interfaces file is like this:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
        address 192.168.250.57
        netmask 250.250.250.0
        gateway 192.168.250.1

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge-ifaces enp3s0
        bridge-ports enp3s0
        up ifconfig enp3s0 up

Comment: about the containers, they use netplan. They just retrive an ipaddress from the dhcp server. I have given them a static ip address in the dhcp server, in stead of them directly, because it seemed easier.